Update spring boot from 2.7.18 to 3.2.5
I am trying to update from spring boot 2.7.18 to 3.2.5 and have this in pom.xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        <netty-handler.version>4.1.92.Final</netty-handler.version>
        <xercesImpl.version>2.12.2</xercesImpl.version>
        <powermock.version>2.0.9</powermock.version>
        <springdoc.version>1.6.15</springdoc.version>
        <jakarta-servlet.version>6.0.0</jakarta-servlet.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>${xercesImpl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.21</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>auth0-spring-security-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.70</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.encoder</groupId>
            <artifactId>encoder</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.351</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

And have this for application
    @OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @Info(
        title = "...",
        description = "...",
        version = "2.2"))
        @SpringBootApplication
        @EnableDiscoveryClient
        @ConditionalOnCloudPlatform(KUBERNETES)
        public class Application{...}

After trying to run the project I am getting
2024-May-22 21:56:39.351 WARN  [main] o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
2024-May-22 21:56:39.356 INFO  [main] o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger -
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-May-22 21:56:39.377 ERROR [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:
Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.
Action:
Check your application's dependencies for a supported servlet web server.
Check the configured web application type.

Well the error tells you what is wrong. You clearly exculde tomcat and are wondering why it complains that it isn't starting? You also have conflicting dependencies it seems in your pom.xml.

@M.Deinum excluding tomcat or no, error stays the same)

Then fix your conflictong/incompatible dependencies. Remove the version from spring-cloud-starter-security. Remove the jakarta.servlet-api dependency as that is included in Tomcat already. Upgrade the spring-boot-admin-starter-client to version 3.2.3.

@M.Deinum Remove the version from spring-cloud-starter-security - this is needed, otherwise it will fail with error "unknown was not found"
jakarta.servlet-api  - this I removed
spring-boot-admin-starter-client - this updated
but I have the same error

If the spring-cloud-starter-security version is needed you will need to look for a proper replacement as that comes from a different (and incompatible) version of Spring Cloud. Next to that your app will only run on kubernetes, if you try to run it locally it won't due to your conditional.

In one application with Jetty EE10 servlet-api 6 with AOT enabled or not it is the same one of that not defined bean which was in previous version so it expects to be something added or changed.

I merely made an override and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78691546/class-path-resource-jakarta-servlet-filter-class-cannot-be-opened-because-it-d/78805324#comment139516029_78805324 .
